# SSH into multiple machines and run multiple commands

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

Writing a script to ssh into multiple machines and running multiple commands. However once the ssh is successful I get the following from each host without a single commands executing, the for loop works fine and I am able to ssh successfully into all the machines.

> Connection closed by host port 22

If I exclude the -tt flag in ssh I also get,

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

How do I get the following script to execute successfully on the machines.

Below is the script I am using

```sh
for vm_ip in "${vm_ip_array[@]}"
do

ssh -tt -i {$key_pair} {$username}@${vm_ip} << HERE

[do multiple stuff here like update packages and other maintainence stuff (sudo commands)]

exit

HERE

done
```

Additional Info : I run a few export statements as well, will that be causing an issue?

Would it be recommended to have the multiple commands as a script on the individual machines? Updating the scripts this way is a nightmare though.

Comment: add a `set -x` at the beginning of the HERE-doc and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an escaping issue. The HERE document is subject of parameter expansion if the word is not quoted.

So try:

```
ssh -tt -i {$key_pair} {$username}@${vm_ip} << 'HERE'
#                                              ^    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use [shellcheck for debugging](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

For instance, it would tell you:

```
{$keypair}: This { is literal. Check expression (missing ;/\n?) or quote it.
```

In other words, I would use `${key_pair}`, not `{$key_pair}`:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
for vm_ip in "${vm_ip_array[@]}"
do

ssh -tt -i "${key_pair}" "{$username}@${vm_ip}" << HERE

[do multiple stuff here like update packages and other maintainence stuff (sudo commands)]

exit

HERE

done
```